# AWS S3 sync with Cloudfront (Cache time?)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Is there a cache time for images that I deleted on my S3 Storage which is connected to an Cloundfront CDN?

I deleted 3 images 30 minutes ago and they are still available over the Cloudfront CDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the cache time is equivalent, to the TTL time value you select in CloudFront or the default average value is one day. If you need to clear the cache, run an [invalidation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html).

More details on CloudFront TTL is given in following links.

- [Specifying how long object stays in CloudFront Edge Cache](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html)
- [CloudFront Default TTL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesDefaultTTL)